# Как указать системе Android что мое приложение может воспроизводить видео файлы?

Tags: android

Суть в том что бы при открытии файла мое приложение отображалось в списке доступных.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос на stackoverflow.com: [How can I enable users to play video using my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370875/how-can-i-enable-users-to-play-video-using-my-app)

Пример работы [intent-filter](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/64-urok-26-intent-filter-praktika.html)